# Schema.org itemscope in body?

Tags: microdata, schema.org

I'm quite new in Microdata / Schema.org, so still finding my way around.
Since I understood that it is all about placing content in relations and references, is it a good (or bad) idea to put an entire web page for a company in one `itemscope` by adding it to the `body` tag? So you would get a structure like:

```html
<body itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/BarOrPub">
    <header>
        <img itemprop="logo" src="logo.jpg" alt="Logo" />
        <h1 itemprop="name">The Bar</h1>
    </header>
    <p>Bla bla</p>
    <table itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/OpeningHoursSpecification">
        <tr><th itemprop="dayOfWeek">Monday</th><td itemprop="opens">17:00-02:00</td></tr>
        <tr><th itemprop="dayOfWeek">Tuesday</th><td itemprop="opens">17:00-02:00</td></tr>
        <tr><th itemprop="dayOfWeek">Wednesday</th><td itemprop="opens">17:00-02:00</td></tr>
        <tr><th itemprop="dayOfWeek">Thursday</th><td itemprop="opens">17:00-02:00</td></tr>
        <tr><th itemprop="dayOfWeek">Friday</th><td itemprop="opens">17:00-02:00</td></tr>
    </table>
    <p>Bla bla</p>
    <div itemprop="address" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress">
        <span itemprop="streetAddress">straatnaam huisnummer</span>
        <span itemprop="addressLocality">Plaats</span>
    </div>
</body>
```

And if this is a good idea, can I use `itemtype` "OpeningHoursSpecification" like I did above, or do I need to make it a child of an `itemprop`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can use the `body` (or even the `html`) element.

It’s also allowed to add items (like OpeningHoursSpecification) as childs. But note these only have a relation to the parent item if you use a property (`itemprop`) to "link" them (like you did with PostalAddress by using the `address` property.)

So if you want to state that this is the OpeningHoursSpecification for the BarOrPub, you should use the [`openingHoursSpecification`](http://schema.org/openingHoursSpecification) property:

```html
<body itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/BarOrPub">

  <table itemprop="openingHoursSpecification" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/OpeningHoursSpecification">
  </table>

  <div itemprop="address" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress">
  </div>

</body>
```

(I’m not sure and did not check if your use of OpeningHoursSpecification in itself is correct, but that would be off-topic for this question anyway.)

Comment: Thanks! So can I learn from this that 'Child' itemtypes, always need to be preceeded by an itemprop?

Comment: @Gooly: This is not required. But if you don’t use an `itemprop`, there is no relation between these items. For an example, see the second part of [my answer on Webmasters SE](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/59369/17633).

Comment: Thanks again. So it depends on several things, like the structure of the information, whether it's better to do it or not.